# Loading images from URL which is behind oAuth

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am developing a google chrome extension which retrieves JSON from server after passing oAuth authorization. The json contains URL for images which I want to show on desktop notification. But I need to pass the oAuth access token along with this request as well. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a Google service to fetch the JSON and images from?

If so, you can try appending the oAuth token as the following get parameter in the image url.

```
access_token
```

eg.

```
<image url>?access_token=<oauth2 access token>
```